# Error in creating tpm virtual smart card on Windows 10

Tags: smartcard, windows-10-universal, tpm

When I try to create a tpm virtual smart card under in command line with adminstrator privilege,

it returns the error: **the card cannot be accessed because the maximum number of PIN entry attempts has been reached**. (The error code is 0x8010006c.)

The command I use is :  **tpmvscmgr.exe create /name tpmvsc /pin default /adminkey random /generate.**

Anybody knows what's wrong with it?

Comment: I seen your same issue has been deleted in the MSDN, have you already resolve your issue?

Comment: @Sunteen, yet till now. I re-asked this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the error code, we know that the TPM is locked. So after I clear TPM with TPM management, the error doesn't come out again.